# Why can't you set a property on an instance of a class?

Tags: python, properties

setattr can be used on either a class or an instance of the class:

```
>>> class C(object):
...   pass
... 
>>> myc = C()
>>> setattr(myc, "val1", 1)
>>> setattr(myc, "val2", 2)
>>> myc.val1
1
>>> myc.val2
2
>>>
```

However, when I try and set a property I get something unexpected:

```
>>> setattr(myc, "val3", property(lambda self: 3))
>>> myc.val3
<property object at 0x7f4d2f30c418>
```

I get the behavior I expected when I set the property to the class instead of the instance:

```
>>> setattr(C, "val4", property(lambda self: 4))
>>> myc.val4
4
```

What is happening when I try and set property on an instance of a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a property on an instance because you can't. Well, you can, but as you have discovered, it won't work. Properties only work when set on the class; that's how it's designed. For details on how the underlying feature (descriptors) works, see the [Descriptor HowTo](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html).